# How to decode U.P.S. Information from UPS MaxiCode Barcode?

Tags: 2d, barcode, ups

I recently purchased a 2D Barcode reader. When scanning a U.P.S. barcode, I get about half of the information I want, and about half of it looks to be encrypted in some way. I have heard there is a UPS DLL.

Example - Everything in bold seems to be encrypted, while the non-bold text contains valuable, legitimate data.

[)>01961163522424800031Z50978063UPSN12312307G:%"6*AH537&M9&QXP2E:)16(E&539R'64O

In other words, this text seems OK - and I can parse the information
[)>01961163522424800031Z50978063UPSN123123 ...

While, this data seems to be encrypted
... 07G:%"6*AH537&M9&QXP2E:)16(E&539R'64O

Any Ideas???

---

Everything I read on the internet says I should be able to read this thing. I'm just not finding any information on specifics. The "encrypted" info contains street address, package number (like 1/2), weight, and several other items Im dying to get my hands on. I suppose I will contact UPS directly.

Comment: In barcoding, "Decode" generally means turning the bars into text. The barcode symbology doesn't offer any further encoding/decoding of the text itself.

There is software available to "Encode", which means "Print the graphics on a printer". For Decoding, you need a scanner and drivers.

Answer (score 3):

The data after the SCAC is compressed and requires a DLL or some other component from UPS in order to decode.  Note that a MaxiCode holds only about 100 characters of data so compression is required in order to encode more shipping data.

Comment: Andyknas is correct. I have used this dll, it is UPS specific.

Comment: I can confirm also with @Jonesome that Andyknas is correct here.  This is a proprietary UPS component that decodes secondary Maxicode information.  Usually, this is something like shipping floor/building/suite data.  The data is compressed, and the UPS component decompresses it.

Comment: Hm, not saying you guys are wrong. However, on the Wikipedia page it says "MaxiCode is a public domain, machine-readable symbol system originally created and used by UPS." I would think if this is public domain that tools/documentation to write programs for it would be more readily available.

Comment: The spec is public, but Maxicode only allows for a certain char length, thus they compress data using a proprietary DLL to get more data into the avail bytes. The DLL is only avail from UPS.

Comment: How would one go about obtaining this DLL? I've been looking through the UPS dev center with no luck...I need to actually be able to encode this piece on a ZPL label. Without encoding, our data strings end up being too long on a rare occasion, causing the Maxicode to come out as a black bar with the text "Invalid Line".

Comment: It's not publicly available. You'd need to work with your UPS rep to get access to the DLL. It's ancillary data that you'd be encoding - the standard data to do a label should be fine in the Maxicode to get a proper barcode. If the data is too long, you should be truncating per the spec.

Comment: @Jonesome sorry for the response to a really old post. However, I was just wondering something. You say you "have used this dll" before. Where did you get it? I am trying to get it the right way but getting the runaround. My rep says he doesn't know anything about it and to call developer support. I talked to UPS developer support and they don't know anything about a dll. It is like it doesn't exist to UPS even though some say they have used it before. Is it a magic dll?

Comment: @MichaelBedford I built a manifest system and went thru UPS certification and did not need the DLL. Why do you need to send more data?

Comment: @andyknas We have a corporate package tracking solution. I can read the MaxiCode 2D barcode just fine and get the tracking number which is about all I can get from the 1D barcode too. However, I would like to get the recipient name from the barcode scan too. This is to help me automate the delivery or routing of packages internally by knowing the recipient from the scan. FedEx allows this in their PDF417 2D barcode. I assume it is in the MaxiCode too but in the compressed "jibberesh" part of the scan.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be [well-documented](http://www.idautomation.com/maxicodefaq.html) ... anything cryptic is likely to be info the shipper is including for their own (or their customer's) purposes.

Comment: The documentation you refer to is maxicode generally, and does not deal with the compression that the OP is asking for. The andyknas response below is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the block of characters you get when scanning those barcodes is divided up into blocks using non-printing characters, so trying to view the characters without knowing how they are divided by the encoder is tough. Look for info on the format in which they store their data, or find a decoder that will display those characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a page I have come across before, however, this page discusses ENCODING a barcode, using plain English and some component. The information used to ENCODE is the information I would like to retrieve when DECODING.

Like I said, when the information is RETRIEVED, half of the information comes out Garbled (encrpyted?) and there is no documentation about to decrypt that code...

According to the link you sent me, I should see something like this:

[)>01963360910628400021Z14647438UPSN410E1W1951/1Y135ReoTAMPAFL

However, I get something like this:

[)>01961163522424800031Z50978063UPSN12312307G:%"6*AH537&M9&QXP2E:)16(E&539R'64O

This leads me to believe the page you sent me is either out-of-date, or that it is simply a reference for how to use their controls to encode, not decode.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you suppose that UPS wants you to decode that part? Moreover, I believe that the piece of code is not encoded - it may be ID of something in their DB.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the unreadable part is not UPS data, but private data intentially obfuscated by agreement between the shipper and receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Check this site out it provides a free decode app.

MaxiCode Barcode FAQ & Tutorial by IDAutomation®
Maxicode is an international 2D (two-dimensional) barcode that is currently used by UPS on shipping labels for world-wide addressing and package sortation. ...

http://www.idautomation.com/maxicodefaq.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/patents/US7039496 has quite a bit of information about the encoded data in images 3-12.  It looks like the first gives the uncompressed format, while the second is a compression dictionary.  The description makes reference to a lot of ANSI standards that are beyond my comprehension, but it does appear that what you're seeing is a format `'07'` string, so perhaps there's enough information here to do a complete decode?

Bearing in mind, of course, that this is part of a patent and that implementing it without paying royalties could get you in trouble.  IANAL