# Decoding UPS Maxicode

Tags: java, encoding, 2d, barcode, ups

I am trying to decode UPS Maxicode in java and getting the following result :

```
[)>02967780900008400031Z49675335UPSN330W9107$FL:X-/,UY
JKY -M,R('3(PH6W )
0.SXI#Z%H(J
```

It gives the house number and street name at the end on the article link below:

http://www.idautomation.com/maxicodefaq.html#Reading-MaxiCode

I have not been able to figure out if the symbols at the end are encrypted or confidential information as i read in one of the topics on stack overflow.

If anyone has any ideas regarding this it will be great help.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is compressed and requires a DLL from UPS to decode. Maxicode only holds about 100 characters so compression is needed to encode more shipping data.

See [Alternate Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369862/how-to-decode-u-p-s-information-from-ups-maxicode-barcode) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote and currently maintain the UPS MaxiCode library.  Compressed MaxiCodes require an additional, proprietary, UPS-owned DLL to decompress.  The MaxiCodes that are typically printed either contain < 100 characters (uncompressed), or contain what we call "Extended" fields, which must be compressed since they exceed 146 characters.  Unfortunately, for the public, this means you can decode uncompressed MaxiCodes, but not decompress compressed MaxiCodes.  ID Automation sells a Font and utility that can be used to both produce and decompress compressed MaxiCodes.