# How can i decode UPS maxicode barcode

Tags: barcode, ups

I have a maxicode UPS barcode on an image which I need to decode.

1. Any known .Net utilities?
2. The data AFAIK is internaly encoded, which mean I need some UPS stuff.

Does someone have it? How can I get it?

Comment: What have you tried already? So we know what NOT to try again. Don't forget you did not pay us.

Comment: Thanks i managed to find a utility to decode the barcode using VintaSoft.

Comment: Now i am trying to decode the string i get, it seems part of the sting is decoded....looking in former questions....seems this is a known issue, Does some have a dll, algorithm to decode it.
this is the information i get 

“[)>?01?96100282011?840?067?1Z92835413?UPSN?49345R?

07FCFTQA""'1O65,'OMH XQ(+R$S3%J661 L5Z'?/7KZLP

First line i manged to parss, the second line seems like encoded data

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode U.P.S. Information from UPS MaxiCode Barcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369862/how-to-decode-u-p-s-information-from-ups-maxicode-barcode)